# Are cross-site scripting vulnerabilities the responsibility of the network/systems admin or developer?

Tags: vulnerabilities

I'm just curious about this.
Say the system was 100% patched up.
Should the administrator also be responsible for cross-site scripting issues?

Comment: Define responsibility?  You aren't expecting the sysadmin to fix the broken application code do you?

Comment: responsibility of making sure they're not there.

Comment: A sysadmin doesn't necessarily have access to the code, and doesn't necessarily have any background in software development.  How should he know if a issue is present or not?  If the sysadmin is made aware of an issue, he may help avoid it.

Comment: that the vulnerabilities aren't there? Sysadmins aren't in charge of QA for coders nor code auditing.

Comment: @John Generically, finding XSS vulnerabilities is a job for whoever's responsible for auditing the environment's security.  The person who gets that responsibility is an organizational decision.

Answer (score 3):

This might get closed for being argumentative, but it seems to be the responsibility of the admin to get the patches in place and fix/contain problems, and the developer is responsible for the actual fix to the application/site.

Admins can't patch what there's no patch for. But they do have to be responsible for trying to clean up the mess (disaster/data recovery) and containment (monitoring for problems, detecting an issue, restoring service, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is either 'all of the above', or 'depends on the environment'.

I am sure some issues may be mitigated by certain configurations on the server.  Therefor, the sysadmin should fix and modify any configurations to avoid any issues.

But the person who developed the code, should be fixing the code.  Or at least it should be someone with a strong background in software development or security.